# Save Result of SQL Statement to Use Elsewhere

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to figure out a way to write an sql query for the number of files that have been sent since 2014-07-01 (the following example should result in **4**). I have two different tables that I need to query against because the date is only available in the first one. They are as follows:

messages:

```
________________________________
messageid | Message | datesent |
1           xxxx      2014-06-30
2           xxxx      2014-07-01
3           xxxx      2014-07-03
```

files:

```
________________________________
filename        |   messageid
red.txt             1
blue.txt            1
green.txt           1
fish.pdf            2
google.doc          3
bing.doc            3
duckduckgo.doc      3
```

So I have a one to many relationship seeing as one message can have more than one file attached to it.

So far I have used the following to get the `messageid` of the first message since 2014-07-01.
`SELECT (messageid) FROM messages WHERE (datesent) = '2014-07-01' LIMIT 1`
I suspect I need to use this as a starting point, but I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select count(0)
from messages as m
join files as f on f.messageid=m.messageid
where m.datesent>'2014-07-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM messages INNER JOIN files ON messages.messageid = files.messageid
WHERE datesent >= '2014-07-01';
```